# Can I use CapsLock as Hyper in a keyboard shortcut for window tiling?

Tags: keyboard, window-manager, keybindings

[Update: Per agarza's suggestion below, I've looked into Rectangle.  It's based on Spectacle so it was familiar enough.  <strike>I checked "Remove keyboard shortcut restrictions" in settings, and that allowed my now-Hyper CapsLock key as a usable modifier.</strike>

Second update: It looks like "Hyper + Left Arrow" is actually registering as Home, which means I can't use the Home key on my USB keyboard as intended.  I suspect it's just treating Hyper like a second Function.  So I'll leave this open for ideas for now.]

My goal is to use CapsLock + Left/Right Arrow for left/right window tiling.

I use Spectacle for my window tiling.  I currently have Command + Option + Left/Right for the window tiling shortcuts. In general, I'm keen to use a shortcut that could not possibly have a purpose in any app. I would like to free those up for their intended use in Excel. I just set up Karabiner-Elements with [CapsLock mapped to Hyper](https://github.com/Vonng/Capslock).  I had hoped to remap the tiling shortcut, but Spectacle only recognizes the standard modifier keys.

I prefer a FOSS solution or at least a no-cost one. I'm looking into ShiftIt.  I know Spectacle is no longer actively maintained, and ShiftIt hasn't updated its README in 14 months, so I'm not sure.  Is there something I haven't thought of?  What works for you?

Comment: Have you looked into [Rectangle](https://github.com/rxhanson/Rectangle)? It is based on Spectacle.

Comment: Just did.  This looks good!  Thanks for the link!

Comment: I would recommend putting your "update" into an answer so others will see how you solved your own problem.